# Writing generic error handling function (Must function)

Tags: go, generics, error-handling

I know that Go will not have generics in the future and there are some recommendations to replace them by other constructs. But with my example below I got stuck.

```
func P(any interface{}, err error) (interface{}) {
    if err != nil {
        panic("error: "+ err.Error())
    }
    return any
}
```

As you might guess, I'm trying to just fail on any error and want to put `P()` just around any function that is returning two results and the second is an error. This is working fine, but `any` is losing it's type information and is only an empty interface in the result.

As I'm also calling lib functions I don't see a way to address this with Interfaces or Reflection.

Any ideas? Am I totally on the wrong track or close to the goal?

Comment: Don't do it. Just write `if err != nil` a lot for a bit and it gets less annoying. If you write something where totally repetitive `err != nil`s constitute too much of your code, you can [write helpers that assign the error somewhere](http://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values), or if some or all errors definitely sink the entire operation, write a panic-on-unrecoverable-error wrapper like `mustWrite` and then `recover` from the panic before it can get out of your package.

Comment: I'd recommend you stop trying to fit "language X's way of doing things" into Go code. Go has explicit error handling everywhere and no true exceptions (panic/recover are not meant for the same thing as C++/Java exceptions). In particular, don't **ever** write a Go package that panic's on something like `os.Open` returning an `os.PathError`.

Comment: Even if you ever find a place where you want to panic on errors, just `panic(err)`. The output on if unrecovered will be nearly the same but `recover` will get the original error rather than a string representation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution would be to [`go generate`](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1V03LUfjSADDooDMhe-_K59EgpTEm3V8uvQRuNMAEnjg/edit) your `P()` function, one for each concrete type you need to work with.
See examples in:

- "[Generic programming in Go using "`go generate`"](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?http://www.onebigfluke.com/2014/12/generic-programming-go-generate.html)".
- "[joeshaw/gengen](https://github.com/joeshaw/gengen)"
- "[cheekybits/genny](https://github.com/cheekybits/genny)"
- "[clipperhouse/gen](https://github.com/clipperhouse/gen)"
- "[Achieving type generic functions in Go, without using reflections](https://medium.com/@motemen/achieving-type-generic-functions-in-go-without-using-reflections-40bc06111970)"

That would make calling those lib functions easier, since the concrete P () implementations generated would use the right type instead of interface{}.

Answer (score 9):

**Go 1.18 generics update:** Go 1.18 adds generics support, it is now possible to write a generic `Must()` function:

```
func Must[T any](v T, err error) T {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return v
}
```

This is available in [`github.com/icza/gog`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/icza/gog), as [`gog.Must()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/icza/gog#Must) (disclosure: I'm the author).

Original, pre-1.18 answer follows.

---

What you want to do *would* require generics but as you already mentioned, Go does not support generic types. Therefore, you can't create a general function which would not lose the type.

You have to create such a function for each type you want to support. Note that the standard library already contains some of these going under the name `MustXXX()`, which you can use out of the box, for example:

[`template.Must(t *Template, err error) *Template`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Must)

Or "similar" functions which suppress the `error` but if one still occurs, panics, for example:

[`regexp.MustCompile(str string) *Regexp`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#MustCompile) (suppresses `error` but panics if `str` is not a valid regexp)

Answer (score 4):

If you plan on just panicking on errors *(bad idea)* or logging them, then just define a function to do so and use it. E.g.

```
func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}

// ...

func foo() {
    a, err := doA()
    checkErr(err)
    b, err := doB()
    checkErr(err)
    // etc.
}
```

The user twotwotwo has already linked to the [Errors are values](http://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values) article that shows more examples on how to make error handling less repetitive. But I would recommend just write the whole `if err != nil` thing, because in my experience every third error, if not second, requires some additional handling.

Answer (score 1):

#### Go 1.18 and above

You can write a generic `Must` function without sacrificing type safety. It looks like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "errors"
)

func Must[T any](v T, err error) T {
    if err != nil {
        panic("error: " + err.Error())
    }
    return v
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Must(test1())) // 450
    fmt.Println(Must(test2())) // panics...
}

func test1() (int, error) {
    return 450, nil
}

func test2() (string, error) {
    return "", errors.New("problem")
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/U1MIHDic9Bn